# How to render OpenAI gym in google Colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory, openai-gym

I'm trying to use OpenAI gym in google colab. As the Notebook is running on a remote server I can not render gym's environment.

I found some solution for Jupyter notebook, however, these solutions do not work with colab as I don't have access to the remote server.

I wonder if someone knows a workaround for this that works with google Colab?

Comment: I've found a better method at this [link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1flu31ulJlgiRL1dnN2ir8wGh9p7Zij2t). This method creates a video!

Comment: now broken at the pacman stage:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-b5464006c7a8> in <module>()
----> 1 env = wrap_env(gym.make("MsPacman-v0"))

Exception: ROM is missing for ms_pacman, see https://github.com/openai/atari-py#roms for instructions

Comment: For anyone that is reading this in 2023, I have a working implementation on my github page using Gymnasium (the current maintained fork of Open AI gym) https://github.com/hom-bahrani/Gymnasium-Colaboratory-Starter

Answer (score 26):

Korakot's answer is not correct.

You can indeed render OpenAi Gym in colaboratory, albiet kind of slowly using none other than matplotlib.

Heres how:

Install **xvfb** & other dependencies (Thanks to Peter for his comment)

```
!apt-get install x11-utils > /dev/null 2>&1 
!pip install pyglet > /dev/null 2>&1 
!apt-get install -y xvfb python-opengl > /dev/null 2>&1
```

As well as **pyvirtual display**:

```
!pip install gym pyvirtualdisplay > /dev/null 2>&1
```

then import all your libraries, including **matplotlib** & **ipythondisplay**:

```
import gym
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython import display as ipythondisplay
```

then you want to import Display from pyvirtual display & initialise your screen size, in this example 400x300... :

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
display = Display(visible=0, size=(400, 300))
display.start()
```

last but not least, using gym's **"rgb_array" render** functionally, render to a "Screen" variable, then plot the screen variable using Matplotlib! (rendered indirectly using Ipython display)

```
env = gym.make("CartPole-v0")
env.reset()
prev_screen = env.render(mode='rgb_array')
plt.imshow(prev_screen)

for i in range(50):
  action = env.action_space.sample()
  obs, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
  screen = env.render(mode='rgb_array')

  plt.imshow(screen)
  ipythondisplay.clear_output(wait=True)
  ipythondisplay.display(plt.gcf())

  if done:
    break

ipythondisplay.clear_output(wait=True)
env.close()
```

Link to my working Colaboratory notebook demoing cartpole:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/16gZuQlwxmxR5ZWYLZvBeq3bTdFfb1r_6

Note: not all Gym Environments support "rgb_array" render  mode, but most of the basic ones do.

Comment: looks like your nb no longer works. there are some conflict installing xvfb for the latest colab. even with the recommended `apt --fix-broken install`, the issue won't be fixed

Comment: This is a solution, but a terrible solution. The frame rate is very crappy

Comment: It is broken right now to fix it you need to add: `!apt-get install x11-utils > /dev/null 2>&1` and `!pip install pyglet==v1.3.2`

Comment: This works for me, 2020/07/21

Comment: This works for me but I need to use `nvidia-xconfig` to create a GL context.

Comment: Just checking, it is working :) 2023/07/15

Answer (score 11):

Try this :-

```
!apt-get install python-opengl -y

!apt install xvfb -y

!pip install pyvirtualdisplay

!pip install piglet


from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
Display().start()

import gym
from IPython import display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')
env.reset()
img = plt.imshow(env.render('rgb_array')) # only call this once
for _ in range(40):
    img.set_data(env.render('rgb_array')) # just update the data
    display.display(plt.gcf())
    display.clear_output(wait=True)
    action = env.action_space.sample()
    env.step(action)
```

This worked for me so I guess it should also work for you.

Comment: Not working for me giving the following error
" NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
...
NameError: name 'base' is not defined"

Comment: This render is on par with matplotlib with no extra install. Thread is closed but I think this is the best answer now:

from IPython.display import clear_output, display
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

for img in imgs:
     display(Image.fromarray(np.array(img), 'RGB'), clear=True)

Answer (score 5):

I recently had to solve the same problem and have written up a [blog post](https://davidrpugh.github.io/stochastic-expatriate-descent/openai/binder/google-colab/2020/04/16/remote-rendering-gym-envs.html) with my solution. For ease of reference I am re-posting the TLDR; version here.

Paste this code into a cell in Colab and run it to install all of the dependencies.

```
%%bash

# install required system dependencies
apt-get install -y xvfb x11-utils

# install required python dependencies (might need to install additional gym extras depending)
pip install gym[box2d]==0.17.* pyvirtualdisplay==0.2.* PyOpenGL==3.1.* PyOpenGL-accelerate==3.1.*
```

And then start a virtual display in the background.

```
import pyvirtualdisplay


_display = pyvirtualdisplay.Display(visible=False,  # use False with Xvfb
                                    size=(1400, 900))
_ = _display.start()
```

In the [blog post](https://davidrpugh.github.io/stochastic-expatriate-descent/openai/binder/google-colab/2020/04/16/remote-rendering-gym-envs.html) I also provide a sample simulation demo that demonstrates that the above actually works.

Comment: this worked for me. I visited the blog post and followed the code.

Comment: @JuanZamora could you share your notebook where this worked? This does not work for me (see https://imgur.com/a/Irmx2G6).

Comment: @elexhobby here: https://github.com/drzamoramora/4-Symbolic-AI/blob/main/Otros/1-Lunar-Lander-open-ai-gym.ipynb

Comment: The code in the answer only gives you a headless display, it doesn't play back the video. The full extract in the blog post uses `matplotlib` like other answers here (note you'll need to set the render mode when initialising the gym environment, not when calling render). The code linked from @JuanZamora 's comment achieves smoother rendering by collating the frames during simulation then playing them back afterwards with `matplotlib.animation` - I'd encourage Juan to submit this as a separate answer as it's superior to the others here!

Answer (score 3):

By far the best solution I found after spending countless hours on this issue is to record & play video. It comes UX wise very close to the real render function.

**Here is a Google colab notebook that records & renders video.** 
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/12osEZByXOlGy8J-MSpkl3faObhzPGIrB

enjoy :)

Comment: I'm trying to run [video in Colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60886590/how-to-setup-pyglet-to-work-with-manim-in-colab). Do you know is it possible?