# Problems pip installing Box2D

Tags: python

I'm learning Reinforcement learning and I'm having the following errors.

Error(1) = I can't set up the 'CarRacing-v0' gym environment without Box2D

Error(2) = I can't pip install the Box2D module.

Does someone know how to interpret these errors and help me fix this?

---

[image]

[image]

Edit:

When trying to pip install box2d-py I get this error:

[image]

Answer (score 15):

Mac users should try:

1. `brew install swig`
2. `pip install box2d-py`
3. `pip install box2d`

terminates without errors under macOS Mojave (10.14)

Comment: I am using windows.  Do you know how to do this on windows or how to fix the error I posted?

Comment: worked for me on M1 Monterrey (12.6)

Comment: worked for me on Ventura (13.3)

Answer (score 9):

Windows users need to do as follows:

- [Download SWIG with the prebuilt executable](https://sourceforge.net/projects/swig/files/swigwin/) and extract somewhere on your PC. **Please note**: I don't think SWIG 4.0 is compatible with Box2D yet, at time of writing SWIG 3.0.12 must be used.
- Add the SWIG directory containing swig.exe to system PATH environment variable.
- Install Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0. Get it with "[Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/)".
- `pip install box2d`
- `pip install box2d-py`

Comment: I wonder if it needs exactly MS VC++ 14.0? 
I've just installed MS VC Build Tools 2019, but swig do NOT see it during ```pip install box2d``` :(

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm running Build Tools 2017 so if you're having problems then perhaps try that.  It can be downloaded here: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/

Also remember if you have amended your PATH variable then you need to start a new cmd prompt to pick up the changes.  If you run swig.exe from a command prompt you should get a response back.

Comment: Great post, thanks. Be careful to download the right tools from the Microsoft site - I had to open the group "Tools for Visual Studio 2019" and then click on "Build Tools for Visual Studio 2019". Then the option to install the Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools is shown during installation. It was a 1 GB approx download

Answer (score 3):

For Ubuntu 20.04.3, I had to run the following:

```
sudo apt-get install swig build-essential python-dev python3-dev
```

before installing `box2d-py`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [`gym`'s `setup.py`](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/setup.py#L11), it appears that the `Box2D` it is trying to import comes from the optional dependency `box2d-py`, so you need to run `pip install box2d-py`.

Comment: When I try that I get another error (see edited question).

Comment: Does the new error give you any idea what the problem is?  I am still trying to get this to work.

Comment: Hi @OliverG , you found any solution? I'm also stuck on the same for a few days.

Comment: @krishna I have yet to find a solution.

Comment: I got past that solution but there is another error again. I used ```!apt-get update
!apt-get install golang libcupti-dev libjpeg-turbo8-dev make tmux htop chromium-browser git cmake zlib1g-dev libjpeg-dev xvfb libav-tools xorg-dev python-opengl libboost-all-dev libsdl2-dev swig

!pip install Box2D
!apt-get install python-box2d
!pip install box2d-py
```
You can try this answer as well : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50719412/7699859

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu 18.04, the following solved my problem with gym and lunar lander :

```
pip3 install box2d-py
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this does not solve the problem but after trying for an entire day I ended up running the game using **Google Colab Notebooks**. Only problem with that is it's a bit hard to render the screen but there is a post on the topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50107530/how-to-render-openai-gym-in-google-colab).

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, pip install was not working for me within my conda environment. My pip would always download the x86 version instead of the arm64 version for my M1 Mac. Instead I pip uninstalled gymnasium and box2d-py and then conda installed them both from conda forge:

```
conda install -c conda-forge box2d-py
conda install -c conda-forge gymnasium
```

After this it worked great and was able to import.

Answer (score -3):

pip install Box2D

it will work 100%

Comment: pip install gym==0.7.4 install this version of gym firsrt then just use this command

Comment: What will `pip install Box2D` do? How will it fix the installation errors? Is it a suggested equivalent?

Comment: It worked for me on WIN10, I don't know why you got downvoted.